# How to unlock glitching fingerprint service forcing me wait for 30 minutes?

Tags: locked-out, samsung-galaxy-s7, fingerprint

Samsung Galaxy S7 fingerpring is glitching: if my finger is wet or dusty, it is trying to detect this case and provide special processing for it. Unfortunately, it can't detect this well and this causing dead loop: it asks to push fingerprint, then it asks to wash button and push again and so on. Pin code entrance doesn't occur.

Today my phone was just lying on the sofa and locked itself for 30 minutes. I hate when irons disobey me! How to unlock it now?

How to absolutely guarantee such thing will never happen again? Both Android and Samsung are glitchy enough itself to have additionally locking for 30 minutes feature!

**UPDATE**

I was able to unlock my phone via Samsung web service. Then I disabled fingerprints and locked phone to try new unlock method and found, that waiting period is still not ended!

Comment: Unfortunately, based on [Android Central's forum](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s7/663631-locked-out-samsung-s7-fingerprint-lock-says-try-again-60-minutes-help.html) this seems like a relatively common issue on Samsung devices...